# Creating JSON using java library

Tags: java, json

I am trying to create a `JSON` as following format -

```
{
 "approvable" : "true",
 "approvedBy" : [user1, user2, user3, user4]
}
```

I have two java variables -

```
boolean approvable;
List<User> approvedBy;
```

If the `approvedBy` list contains all the `Users`, then can I make the `JSON` directly using any `JSON` library? Suppose I want to do something like this -

```
JsonBuilder jb = new JsonBuilder();
jb.add("approvable", true);
jb.add("approvedBy", approvedBy);
```

Ultimately, all I need to do is to simplifying the making of JSON. Can anyone suggest any good JSON library which give me this support?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using the Oracle JSON kit, it sucks.

Comment: Use Jackson (or Gson I suppose). Both of those libraries support automatic binding between JSON and POJOs. Whatever you do, don't waste your time with manual conversion.

Comment: In my opinion/experience, "manual conversion" is less effort (and often fewer lines of code) than dealing with automatic binding to POJOs.  The problem is that many people do not take the time to understand JSON and so feel they must use "cookbook" approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API used is `flexjson`

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Child child2 = new Child("ankur", 23);
        Child child1 = new Child("ankurs", 23);
        Child child3 = new Child("ankurss", 21);

        List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<Child>();
        childList.add(child1);
        childList.add(child2);
        childList.add(child3);

        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setApprovable(true);
        parent.setChildList(childList);
        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        System.out.println(serializer.exclude("*.class").deepSerialize(parent));

    }
```

**Output**

```
{
    "approvable": true,
    "childList": [
        {
            "age": 23,
            "name": "ankurs"
        },
        {
            "age": 23,
            "name": "ankur"
        },
        {
            "age": 21,
            "name": "ankurss"
        }
    ]
}
```